# How to use HTML5 pattern attribute in Pug (Jade) template

Tags: regex, node.js, escaping, pug

With Pug (previously named Jade) templating engine, how can I use the [pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) of an input ?

When I use a pattern like:

```
input( type="tel", pattern="\d{7}" )
```

the rendered pattern is:

```
<input type="tel" pattern="d{7}">
```

I also tried with the [unescaped attribute](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#unescaped) **!=** but it still escapes the `\` character.

Note: it works perfectly with `pattern="[0-9]{7}"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that the `\` character is used to escape Javascripts's own special characters.

You need to escape it so it will be rendered in the pattern, as  [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters).

```
input( type="tel", pattern="\\d{7}" )
```

will render properly as:

```
<input type="tel" pattern="\d{7}">
```

Comment: Be careful, the `\` character is not used to escape Jade's special characters, but rather JavaScript's. The string in the quotation marks are just regular JavaScript strings, and anything else would just complicate stuff.

Comment: Oh, you're right @Timothy, I edited the answer. Thank you!